# How to tell Google that directory doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: joomla, indexing, googlebot, google-search-console

I created health-related site based on Joomla.
I created Google Webmasters account and saw how Google indexed my site.
But then I saw that Google indexed some directory /includes (that I didn't create) and which content was far from health topics.
I deleted this directory, but already for 2 months Google Webmaster shows top keywords from /includes directory.

What should I do to tell Google that directory doesn't exist anymore?

Thank you in advance. In case you need, here is address of site: http://healthfount.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a robots.txt file for your site.

see [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)